# Unable to edit an array in a defined class object (Solved)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, class

I wrote some code for a class called `Player`, which initializes some attributes upon usage. One of the attributes is an array. Here's my simplified code:

```js
class Player {
    constructor(basicStuff) {
        this.basicStuff = basicStuff
        this.keys = [];
    }
    move(event) {
        this.keys[event.key] = true;
        //moves position
    }
    releaseKey(event) {
        //updates the keys pressed
    }
    draw(scene) {
        //draws player
    }
}

const player = new Player("basicStuff");
window.addEventListener('keydown', player.move);
window.addEventListener("keyup", player.releaseKey);
```

So here's the problem: when I run the code and test it, I would get `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'event.key' of undefined"`. It seems like `this.keys` from the const `player` was never defined even though it's very clear that I've done so in the constructor. What should I do so `this.keys` in the `move` method of `player` is not `undefined`?

Note: This piece of Javascript code is cooperating with another Node.js file, if that's helpful to mention.

Comment: Did you mean to use an object instead of an array? `this.keys = {};`

Comment: You have to bind the event listeners to the player: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: The `this` inside `move` will refer to the global window object since JS handles the execution of the function, not the object instance. You could bind the this in your constructor using `this.move = this.move.bind(this)`

Comment: `window.addEventListener('keydown', player.move.bind(player));`  otherwise the method is just a function that ignore which object it is linked to

Comment: So I added multiple bindings similar to "this.move = this.move.bind(this)" but then I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined". It highlights the second method I tried to bind. Even when I only bind the first method, I get "TypeError: chrome[I51][b51][o01[A61]] is not a function".

Comment: Edit: Thanks everyone, I tried all the methods I could find and Mister Jojo's approach was the only one that could solve my problem. Thanks again!